# How to reflect availability from a subscribed Google Calendar to colleagues using Outlook Web Application

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I use a Google Calendar for all of my events. In order to coordinate with team members at another company, I have to use a calendar in Outlook Web Application. I want those team members to be able to see my availability alongside the availability of other team members so that they can schedule meetings at times when everyone is available.

From my Google Calendar, I copied the `Public address in iCal format` url and in Outlook,

I chose `Open calendar`...

[image: contextual menu - other calendars]

and pasted that url as an `Internet calendar`.
[image: open calendar dialog]

Here's what I see in Outlook Web Application.
[image: Outlook calendar]

It is reflecting events from my Google Calendar under the `other calendar`.

When my team members try to look across other people's availability, I think they are right-clicking `other calendars`, choosing `open`, and typing a name into the `from directory` field

[image: open calendar dialog]

Which then lists each person's calendar as another `other calendar`.

How can I get my subscribed Google Calendar availability to be visible to my colleagues in this way?

I searched for this, but all I came up with was [instructions to import or subscribe to another calendar in the first place](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-503ffaf6-7b86-44fe-8dd6-8099d95f38df), and I've already subscribed to my Google Calendar.

Comment: _"...instructions to import or subscribe to another calendar in the first place, which I've already done"_. Which one do you believe you did? Import OR Subscribe? It  seems to me that you subscribed and not imported. Please clarify.

Comment: @marikamitsos Correct, I subscribed. I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow these **3 simple steps**:

1. **Import** (*instead of just subscribing*) **your Google Calendar to the  Outlook Web Application**.
2. **Join** [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/join).
3. **Use this "[Google/Outlook Calendar Sync Tool](https://ifttt.com/applets/323037p-google-outlook-calendar-sync-tool)" excellent applet to sync your calendars**.

Comment: Thanks. I do use IFTTT for other things. I tried that but got this "Could not connect service" error when I tried to connect that applet. https://www.reddit.com/r/ifttt/comments/d5knyb/google_outlook_calendar_sync_tool_could_not/

Comment: That was probably because you hadn't imported your calendar but merely subscribed to it.

Comment: I am not seeing an option to import my calendar. The company may have restricted that - not sure. I see "open calendar" and put the url into "internet calendar". I updated the steps in the question with screenshots.